# Segmental -> [sɛɡ|mɛnt"ə"l] Can I omit the "/ə/" sound?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, vowels, phonology

segmental [sɛɡ|mɛnt**ə**l]

Can I omit the **/ə/** sound?

Due to another dictionary's pronunciation [seɡˈmentl]

Comment: why would you? It's hard to...

Comment: You may find this video useful for American English https://rachelsenglish.com/pronounce-t-dark-l/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can omit the /ə/, but if you do so, you'll have to make the terminal /l/ syllabic.

As I explained in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266963/106592), when we have a sonorant right after an obstruent in an unstressed syllable, the sonorant often tends to be syllabic i.e. it makes a syllable on its own (syllable nucleus).

The second syllable in *segmental* is stressed and the last syllable is unstressed. And we have a sonorant /l/ right after the /t/ (obstruent), so in this case, the /l/ is syllabic.

Syllabic consonants are often longer and more prominent than normal. In the case of *segmental* the air is released [laterally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_release_(phonetics)). Normally, the stops /t/ and /d/ are released by releasing the closure from the centre of the tongue; however, in lateral release, the closure is released from the sides of the tongue.

We symbolise syllabic consonants by a small vertical line below the consonant:

> ### [seɡˈmen.tl̩]

Note, however, that most Americans will drop the /t/ in that position and will pronounce it something like [segˈmeɾ̃əl]<sup>1</sup>. I've explained why Americans drop the /t/'s in that position in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271531/106592). In a nutshell, when a stressed syllable ends in an /n/ and the next unstressed syllable starts with a /t/, Americans are likely to drop the T, so 'internet' becomes *innernet*, 'segmental' becomes *segmennal*, 'counter' becomes *counner* etc.

([Here's](https://youtu.be/vayx9M66AoY) how most Americans pronounce 'segmental'.)

---

1. [ɾ̃] is called a [nasalised flap](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/284947/106592)

Comment: sonorant (/n/) right after an obstruent (/t/), so in case, the /n/ is syllabic?

Comment: I think people who go around talking about segmental features, for example, are not going to drop anything. Not the same as innernet and counner.